# Calculation of max height of ball (level: newbie)

Tags: java, constructor, parameter-passing

I decided to learn some Java. Therefore I've been searching the web for some exercises. Now I'm stuck and would appreciate your help.

I want to calculate the maximum height of a ball I've been throwing from the very ground. Therefore I'm using `height = 0. 5 * speed * speed (in metres per second) / 9.81 (in metres per second²)`.

My class 'Ball'

```
public class Ball {

// Attributes

private static final double GRAVITATION = 9.81;
private static final double SECONDS_OF_HOUR = 3600.0;
private static final double METERS_OF_KILOMETER = 1000.0;


/**Speed of the ball in meters per second. */
private float speed;


// Constructor
public Ball(float speedInKmh) {
}

// Methods
/**
  * @return maximal height in metres.
 */
public double maxHeight() {        
    return 0.5 * speed * speed / GRAVITATION;
}

/**
 * @param kmh  speed in kilometres / hour
 * @return speed in meters / second
 */
private double kmHToMs(double kmh) {
    return kmh * METERS_OF_KILOMETER / SECONDS_OF_HOUR;
}
}
```

My question:
1. Where and when would I use kmHToMs? I mean, I have to use it somewhere to calculate the max height when someone enters e.g. 5 kmh for speed in the command line.

I'd like to write another class 'Balltester'. Here I'd like to test the input of the command line. I'm going to check for numbers > 0. If the input is null or cointains a letter or more I want to exit the program. Do I miss something here? The tester class isn't wirtten yet because I do not know how to start.

I tried to use the constructor with `public static void main(String[] args) {}`, but all I got back by entering 5 kmh for speed was Ball@659e0bfd. So I guess I have to 1. convert the speed parameter somehow and 2. deliver the commando-line parameter in the class 'Balltester' to the constructor Ball.

I appreciate any help and feedback. Thank you in advance.

EDIT
    public class BallTester {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ball(new Ball(5));
    }
         private static void ball(Ball b) {
             b.maxHeight();
                System.out.println(b);

    }

}
```

Comment: What is your `main` method so far?

Comment: Did you notice that your constructor is not actually doing anything with its parameter? Also, did you notice that nothing is setting a value in the `speed` field? These two facts are connected. Also, don't try to print the ball. Just print the result of the method call...

Comment: @RealSkeptic - That is my problem. So I'd assign speedInKmh to speed. Thanks for the tip with not printing the ball.

Comment: But if you assign it directly, then will your formula return the correct value? Try it and see what results you get.

Comment: Well, the result I should get by speed = 5kmh should be about 1,27m. I get 0.0. I'm not gone btw - just trying to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, RealSketpic. Your questions were very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you aren't assigning the speed to the ball. You need to do this in the constructor:

```
public Ball(float speedInKmh) {
    this.speed = kmhToMs(speedInKmh);
}
```

Note that you need to use `kmhToMs(speedInKmh)` since `speedInKmh` is in kilometers/hour and you want `speed` in meters/hour.

Second, in your `ball` method in the `BallTester` class, you are printing out the ball, not the maximum height. You need to change the method to this:

```
private static void ball(Ball b) {
    System.out.println(b.maxHeight());
}
```

---

For your test class, I think this is what you want:

```
public class BallTester {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {        
        int speed;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        string s = scanner.next();
        try {            
            speed = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if (speed > 0) {
                ball(new Ball(5));
            }            
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
             System.out.println("This is not a valid speed.");
        }
    }
}
```